# htaccess redirect to root domain

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have domain name with subdirectory which i want to redirect to root folder.
For example when the users visit here `example.com/contact`, i would like to redirect to `example.com`. Currently are my htaccess code to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you try: `RewriteRule ^subdir(/.*|)$ $1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```